# $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of stationary probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains

Given a discrete time Markov Chain $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ on a finite state space $E = C_1 \cup C_2$, where $C_1, C_2$ are two closed, non equal communicating classes. Assuming that both classes are aperiodic, argue that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_{i_1}(X_n = j) = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_{i_1}(X_n = j)$, where $i_1 \in C_1$ is fixed and $j \in E$.

I was wondering if one can show me the argument of this equality without using stationary probabilities, since they are defined only in the second part of this problem? This is just a portion of a problem I use to study for my exam, not a homework. Thank you in advance!